# I need to find the total number of occurrences of a particular item in JSON Response using postman tool

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

```
[
    {
        "branchCode": "111",
        "referenceNumber": "2222",
        "comments": "Write Off",
        "transactionDate": "2022-02-23T00:00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "accountCode": "MMMM",
        "accountName": "Metal MMMM",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "branchCode": "111",
                "referenceNumber": "3333",
                "allocationDate": "2022-02-23T09:23:57",
                "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client",
                "accountCode": "MMMM",
                "accountName": "Metal MMMM",
                "amount": -0.02
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "branchCode": "222",
        "referenceNumber": "33333",
        "comments": "To write off historic med fee $0",
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-24T00:00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "accountCode": "OOOO",
        "accountName": "Oranga OOOO - AEP",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "branchCode": "222",
                "referenceNumber": "456",
                "allocationDate": "2022-03-24T10:39:02",
                "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client",
                "accountCode": "OOOOP",
                "accountName": "Oranga 0000 - AEP",
                "amount": 94.88
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the above JSON Response i need to find how many Allocations have been done in the entire Response.
Can i do this using a for loop , If so how to use it to iterate through the Array and then count the Allocations item

I tried using the Object.keys(jsondata[0]).length) method. But this is useful to find the length of the items in a specific block.
But i could not understand how to traverse through an array and find the number of allocations

Comment: So you want a postman test that logs the amount of allocations in both objects? So `2` in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get all the `allocations` on which you can call `.length`:

```js
const data = [{"branchCode": "111", "referenceNumber": "2222", "comments": "Write Off", "transactionDate": "2022-02-23T00:00:00", "amount": 0, "accountCode": "MMMM", "accountName": "Metal MMMM", "allocations": [{"branchCode": "111", "referenceNumber": "3333", "allocationDate": "2022-02-23T09:23:57", "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client", "accountCode": "MMMM", "accountName": "Metal MMMM", "amount": -0.02 } ] }, {"branchCode": "222", "referenceNumber": "33333", "comments": "To write off historic med fee $0", "transactionDate": "2022-03-24T00:00:00", "amount": 0, "accountCode": "OOOO", "accountName": "Oranga OOOO - AEP", "allocations": [{"branchCode": "222", "referenceNumber": "456", "allocationDate": "2022-03-24T10:39:02", "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client", "accountCode": "OOOOP", "accountName": "Oranga 0000 - AEP", "amount": 94.88 } ] } ];

const n = data.flatMap(o => o.allocations).length;

console.log(n);
```

Comment: Thank you very much flatMap function resolved my issue .Now it is giving correct number of allocations  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this. Note that it may be necessary to use `JSON.parse` on the data if you receive it as a string.

```js
let jsonData = [
    {
        "branchCode": "111",
        "referenceNumber": "2222",
        "comments": "Write Off",
        "transactionDate": "2022-02-23T00:00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "accountCode": "MMMM",
        "accountName": "Metal MMMM",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "branchCode": "111",
                "referenceNumber": "3333",
                "allocationDate": "2022-02-23T09:23:57",
                "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client",
                "accountCode": "MMMM",
                "accountName": "Metal MMMM",
                "amount": -0.02
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "branchCode": "222",
        "referenceNumber": "33333",
        "comments": "To write off historic med fee $0",
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-24T00:00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "accountCode": "OOOO",
        "accountName": "Oranga OOOO - AEP",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "branchCode": "222",
                "referenceNumber": "456",
                "allocationDate": "2022-03-24T10:39:02",
                "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client",
                "accountCode": "OOOOP",
                "accountName": "Oranga 0000 - AEP",
                "amount": 94.88
            }
        ]
    }
];

let nbAllocations = jsonData.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.allocations.length, 0);

console.log(nbAllocations);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this requirement with the help of `Array.forEach()`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const jsonObj = [
    {
        "branchCode": "111",
        "referenceNumber": "2222",
        "comments": "Write Off",
        "transactionDate": "2022-02-23T00:00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "accountCode": "MMMM",
        "accountName": "Metal MMMM",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "branchCode": "111",
                "referenceNumber": "3333",
                "allocationDate": "2022-02-23T09:23:57",
                "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client",
                "accountCode": "MMMM",
                "accountName": "Metal MMMM",
                "amount": -0.02
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "branchCode": "222",
        "referenceNumber": "33333",
        "comments": "To write off historic med fee $0",
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-24T00:00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "accountCode": "OOOO",
        "accountName": "Oranga OOOO - AEP",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "branchCode": "222",
                "referenceNumber": "456",
                "allocationDate": "2022-03-24T10:39:02",
                "ledgerTypeDescription": "Client",
                "accountCode": "OOOOP",
                "accountName": "Oranga 0000 - AEP",
                "amount": 94.88
            }
        ]
    }
];

let count = 0;

jsonObj.forEach(({ allocations }) => count += allocations.length)

console.log(count);
```